# Match the same character an exact number of times with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python `re` to find a set of the same letter or number repeated a specific number of times.  `(.)` works just fine for identifying what will be repeated, but I cannot find how to keep it from just repeating different characters. here is what I have:

```
re.search(r'(.){n}', str)
```

so for example it would match `9999` from `99997` if `n = 4`, but not if `n = 3`.
thanks

Comment: This website is your friend: http://www.txt2re.com/index-php.php3.

Comment: Can you clarify what you *want* to match and what you *don't* want to match? I don't understand what "I cannot find how to keep it from just repeating different characters" is supposed to mean.

Comment: i want to match anything that repeats n times, so if 9 repeats n times i want 9999, or if T repeats n times i want TTTT, but i dont' want 9897 if i say .{4}

Comment: TBH, it seems like regex is the wrong tool for this job. You can [easily create the string you want to check for](http://ideone.com/nOY4d), so you really don't even need a regex at that point.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL, I don't think this applies. The op wants series of *any* character, not a specific character like `9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
(?:^|(?<=(.)))(?!\1)(.)\2{n-1}(?!\2)
```

This will:

- `(?:^|(?<=(.)))`: Make sure that:

  - `^`: Either we are at the beginning of the string
  - `(?<=(.))`: Either we are not at the beginning of the string; then, capture the character before the match and save it into `\1`
- `(?!\1)(.)`: Match any character that is not `\1` and save it into `\2`
- `\2{n-1}`: Match `\2` n-1 times
- `(?!\2)`: Make sure `\2` cannot be matched looking forward

(The `n-1` is only symbolic; obviously you want to replace this with the actual value of n-1, not with `8-1` or something).

**Important edit**: The previous version of the regex (`(.)\1{n-1}(?!\1)`) does not work because it fails to account for character matching `\1` behind the match. The regex above fixes this problem.

Comment: thanks that looks like it works and i'll check you as you were first, but it's making me wait 4 minutes for some reason or other

Comment: Please re-read the answer; the previous version of my answer did not work. The above should work now.